# How to store .c and .h files in an includepath, separate from source code of current project

Tags: c++, c, ide, include-path

I tried to shorten down my question (the Old question can still be found below)

My current directory structure looks like this

```
C:\users\documents\projects 
    |
    +----- utility
    |         |
    |         +----- include (files not shown)
    |         +----- src
    |                 |
    |                 +----file1.c (and other files not shown)
    |
    +----- proj1
             |
             +----- include (files not shown)
             +----- src
                     |
                     +----- proj_file1.c (and other files not shown)
```

I can include the .h files from *..\utility\include* with `#include <file.h>` to proj1, if I add this directory as **include path** to my IDE (in proj1). Is there an aequivalent solution for the *..\utility\src* files? I am using LPCXpresso IDE on Windows 7. I suppose there is the same solution on any IDE, so I just want to know how this **whatever path** (where .c files will be searched, if not found in the *.\src* directory) is generally called to find it in my project settings.

- I try to avoid using libraries (.lib, .dll)
- I don't want to copy the .c files in each project (proj1, proj2, ..., projn)
- I want to be able to simply edit the .c and .h files and if recompiling proj1 and so on the changes will be applied, as they will for all other projects
- Generating an own makefile may be a solution (but shouldn't there be an Option to add a source-file-path in IDEs?)
- `#include <..\utility\src>` is a non-desired solution as changes to the directory will fource to add this line in each single file, where changing a path in the Options are only some clicks.

Thanks in advance and thanks for the answers up to now

---

**Old Version of my question:**

**Motivation:** Imagine, you write a program in C/C++ in some IDE and have .c and .h source code files as usual. In addition you have a helper.c and helper.h file, were you defined some useful, not project related functions (which can be used in several projects). You want to include these files, but don't want to have them were you store your project related source code.

**As far as I know** .h files can be stored in a separate folder, which is pointed to by the *includepath*. This path can be set in every IDE. Further it changes the

```
#include "helper.h"
```

statement to

```
#include <helper.h>
```

If I put the .c files in the same folder and not include them separately, the compiler will not find them. If I include them as well with

```
#include <helper.c>
```

a multiple inclusion will lead to multiple function deklaration and therefore to a compiler-error. Only solution may be an

```
#ifndef helper_c_
//content of helper.c file
#endif
```

, which is kind of impractical and will always need inclusion of the .h and the .c file. But i only need to have them stored once, with no copies and if i need to change something, it will change in all projects, as they are all pointing to that folder

I also now about library files, where you have an .lib and a .dll file, where the .lib file needs to be pointed at by the library-path and the .dll file needs to be in the same folder as the .exe file afterwards. But that is not what i want.

**My Question:** Is there a possibility to store the .h and .c file (in my current case there are 10 file-pairs) in a separate folder and point at them via an include path or so? I tried googling around, but I think I am not quite sure what i shall look for.

Thanks for help

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention: I use Windows 7, and my current IDE is the LPCXpresso-IDE

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After looking around through all the settings and options I found the following satisfying solution: creating a Link to a source file folder

**This answer applies to the LPCXpresso IDE**

- imagine the folder structure shown in my question
- inside the LPCXpresso IDE -> rightclick on the project -> properties
- navigate to C/C++ General>Paths and Symbols>Source Loacation
- click "Link Folder..."
- in the opened dialog tag the checkbox *Link to folder in the file system*
- click Browse... or enter *C:\users\documents\projects\utility\src*
- click OK
- click Apply
- recompile and be happy :)

Answer (score 2):

OK, suppose you have this directory structure:

```
C:\users\documents\projects 
        |
        +----- utility
        |         |
        |         +----- include (files not shown)
        |         +----- src
        |                 |
        |                 +----file1.c (and other files not shown)
        |
        +----- proj1
                 |
                 +----- include (files not shown)
                 +----- src
                         |
                         +----- proj_file1.c (and other files not shown)
```

And also assume, that the current directory for compilation is in the `proj1/src` directory.  I see at least three solutions to your question:

1. if you really want to `#include` the source files, which I do not recommend doing, just use a relative path to the files i.e.

   ```
   #include "..\..\utility\src\file1.c"
   ```

Now in addition to the issues with including source files, this tends to be very fragile in that if you change the directory structure (or change a name of a directory) everything breaks.  You would need to go back into your source and fix every line of code.

2. As iharob suggested, use a make file to handle this.  In this case, you would have a compile line that looked like this (assuming you are using Microsoft's tool change);

   ```
   cl /I..\..\utility\include ..\..\utility\src\file1.c  /o util_file1.o
   ```

This causes the result of the compilation to be dropped in the current working directory and the linker will be able to find all the object files and combine them together into one executable.  We still are dealing with relative paths here, but all the changes would be in a single file, and by using make variables the changes would be on a single line or two.

3. If the functions in the utility directory are going to be used in multiple projects, my personal favorite solution is to make a utility project that produces a dynamic library (a dll under windows) and link subsequent projects with that library.  You still have to deal with locating where the include files are going to be (maybe a directory at the top level of where all your project folders are?), but to me a library seems cleaner.  It also has the added advantage that if you want to modify the code in the utility project, just recompile the library and the rest of you project will 'see' the modifications with out recompilation of them (assuming you do not modify the interface of the library).

Hope this helps,
T

Comment: Option 1 ist what I really don't want, and what I had to correct, as the "LPC17xx" files, offered by NXP, have exactly this structure... I corrected it to have the way suggested by Tufak. Option 2 sounds good... as below, what might that be called in an IDE - according to "include path" for .h files. Option 3 is a non-desired solution: If I want to make changes I need to go to that "utility project", now I can just click on the "include path" file and change it -> boom chang everywhere

Comment: @Martin not sure why you are shying away from Libraries, they are a powerful mechanism for code reuse.  Consider what you are describing now, and you have these utility files imported into 5 different projs (multiple projs are alluded to in your OP).  Yes, if you need to make a change, and working in e.g. proj3 it is easy to open the file and make the changes.  However, what about the other 4 projects?  You need to open and recompile each for the change to take effect.  With a library, make the change in the lib and it is reflected everywhere the lib is used.  Just something to think about.

Comment: Good answer, with an example and every thing, I didn't know that for `cl` the switch was simple `/I`.

Comment: @thurizas I could make a library, but I wouldn't I then need to copy the .dll to all my projects separately?  - I need to admit that I never created libraries before. For me the solution with a linked source path is the simplest and most obvious solution. I can always see the source files and edit them or look what they are doing. But I agree, if I can rely on the functions and just use them without the need of changing or looking through the functions lines - a library would be a smoother solution.

Comment: @martin If you put the library on a well known search path for the linker (say C:\windows\system32) it will be available to all your programs.  You also could modify your build setting (assuming LPCXpresso has post build setting) so that all your executable are copied in a folder for your executable (say C:\users\bin), and just put your dll (or dlls there).  You will need to add the various *.lib files to your linker command, but there are command line options to do this, and if you place all your *.lib files in the same place it should be easy.

Comment: I trust you that it is possible with libraries. But you have to admit that it is easier just to add a Path to a folder where the files are stored. I don't see any benefit from using library files in this case, i am sorry

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course there is, depending on what compiler you are using there will be a switch to tell the compiler where to search for headers, for `gcc` and some others AFAIK, it's `-I`, so for example suppose that your headers are in the `myproject/headers` directory, the compiler should be invoked like this

```
gcc -I myproject/header ${OTHER_OPTIONS} ${SOURCE_OR_OBJECT_FILES} -o ${OUTPUT_FILE}
```

The usual way to build a project with the `.c` files in different directories is to use a `Makefile` and a program that can parse the `Makefile` and invoke the neecessary commands to build the project.

Comment: I have not much backround information about makefiles, but I always thought, that - assuming I use an IDE - the IDE generates appropriate makefiles, what in accordance means, there has to be some option to set that. What might that path or option be called (as for the .h files it's called "include path")

Comment: There is no reason that an IDE would or wouldn't create a makefile -- some do and some don't.   All a make file is, is a set of rules to build everything in your project, maintaining a list of what objects and/or executable depend on (i.e. foo.o might depend on foo.c, foo.h and bar.h ).  I'm sure IDE's do maintain similiar information, but exactly how is hidden from the average user, but you are correct that there should be a mechanism to import other files into an existing project.

Comment: But even if there was a way, i think you must learn how to write them yourself, you surely will not always write them by hand, but you should learn how they work.

Comment: @iharob I totally agree with you, but I will lern to write them, if I face a more inconvenient situation. But in my special case, of using LPCXpresso IDE for mikrocontroller Programming, I want to use the abilities of the IDE rather then writing my own makefile, as the IDE seems to work fine.

Comment: @iharob i know, i read the stack overflow auestion on that :-), but i need to wait for 2 days. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning: it is generally not a good idea to `#include` source (.c) files. The source files are meant for compilation, not inclusion -- including them may result in strange errors (most prominently, apparent re-definitions of a function).

Here is what I would do (for each project that needs the helper code):

- Add your utility .c files to the project. Look for *Add existing file...* or a similar IDE feature; this ensures that your utility source files, i.e. `helper.c`, get compiled along with your project.
- As for the .h file, include it with `#include <helper.h>`, enabling you to use your utility declarations.
- Finally, find a compiler option called *Include paths*, a.k.a. *-I*, and set it to the folder that contains `helper.h`. This is usually found in *Project options/settings*.

Comment: That's exactly, what I do at the moment, but it seems impractical to me. 1) I need to copy the .c files in each project, 2) if I make changes to one of them, I need to copy the changes in each project. What I am looking for is a solution, where I can tell the compiler a directory to look for the according "include-path-.h-files" source files

Comment: apparent re-definitions of a function? or **re-definitions** of a function?

Comment: Alhtough this is also a good answer, I'd recommend against the IDE for a beginner, because it would hide important details of how to actually build a project.